# How to handle union types globally like apollo-client?. Typescript throws Property 'urls' does not exist on type 'Media' for graphql Union

Tags: typescript, apollo-client, graphql-js, react-query, prisma-graphql

I have a union `type Media = Image | Emoji` and I'm using it on many different and deeply nested entities in my graphql schema. I'm also using **graphql-code-generator** to generate types.
I used to use **apollo-client** to handle my requests and it was handling union types like a charm in the cache.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    possibleTypes: {
      Media: ['Image', 'Emoji'],
      ...
```

But for some reason, I had to migrate to **react-query** and **graphql-request** and now every time I want to use `object.logo: Media` for example and this logo can have different types but typescript throws this error:

```
Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Media'.
  Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Emoji'.
```

I don't want to check for the type each time and cast so I wonder how can I implement this globally like what apollo-client did?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? This is prompting me to reluctantly abandon RQ in favor of Apollo Client :/

Comment: The only way I could manage so far was to use `as` ts keyword to cast the type.
for example:
```const emoji = media as Emoji```